# Print range images get by query in MYSQL- ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, mysql, asp.net

I require to print a range of images that bring in a query, the range can be very large but when printing mean to choose whether you want to print a certain range by nose images if this has to do with JavaScript or with asp. net.

```
  <button name="printButton" id="printButton" type="button" class="btn btn-default"  onclick= "printDiv('printableArea');" runat="server">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="panzoom">
                        <div id="printableArea">
                            <img src="img/descarga.jpg" alt="Visualización del original de la forma migratoria" class="img-responsive" runat="server">
                        </div>   
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function printDiv(divName) {
        var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
        var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
        document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
        window.print();
        document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
        window.onfocus = function () {
            window.close();
        }
        var $section = $('section').first();
        $section.find('.panzoom').panzoom({
            $zoomIn: $section.find(".zoom-in"),
            $zoomOut: $section.find(".zoom-out"),
            $zoomRange: $section.find(".zoom-range"),
            $reset: $section.find(".reset")
        });
    };
</script>
```

As you can see only the image that is inside the div is printed, what I try to do is that when you send print ask if I want to print all that were obtained through a query, that rank to rank, or pages

In this image show the results

[image: Find]

[image: image to print]

The image show in other panel,and the user can print this image,but i want that the user can choose to print a range of images that were found with the inquiry ... ie the results

Comment: Have you attempted to solve this problem? If you have, include your code and research in your question to show what hasn't worked for you. If not, you should attempt to solve it yourself first and then post the code and research here. It makes your question easier for others to answer too!

Comment: I don't fully understand your question : _"what I try to do is that when you send print ask if I want to print all that were obtained through a query"_ how do you plan to do this? What design or UI will you have for the user? What will the page for all images look like? What _images_ does your server return ? What does relevant asp.net code look like ?

Answer (score 3):

You should attach HTML generated by server...

Anyway - I don't think it's JS problem. CSS can solve your problem - you should read about `media="print"` attribute, which can apply CSS only to printed document. I suggest to generate all DIVs with `display:none` attribute, and with `media="print"` overwrite it to show them all.